# how to wait redux action to completely dispatched before dispatching another action?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

As my app grows, now redux state bugs appear. This is because there will be cases where an async action has not been completely dispatched, but other action is dispatched and completed before previous action completed.

Is there a way to make an action waits for prev action to completely dispatched?

The dispatched actions function call will happen on different functions or even in different react components, so promise form of action would not be the solution. I need something that can manage the sequence of actions dispatched by redux, and when needed we can pass sth like `isWaitToComplete` parameter to the action, so that redux knows it will need to wait that particular action before dispatching another action.

Answer (score 0):

My solution like yours, is to set a global status **isWaitToComplete** in your reducer,then change it to true or false,if the last action did't finish,then will not execute the next one.

Comment: Thank you, this is not what I actually need, somehow it surely can address the issue. I hope to have a middleware or built-in functionality from redux itself. Somehow it gives me idea.

Answer (score 0):

Temporarily this is how I solved the issue:

```js
let isLoading = false // alias of isWaitToComplete 

export default function (state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case types.SCREENS_UPDATE_STARTED: {
      ...
      isLoading = true
      ...    
    }
    case types.SCREENS_UPDATE_SUCCESS: {
      ...
      isLoading = false
      ...
    }
    case types.SCREENS_SELECT: {
      const runAfterPrevActionCompletelyDispatched = () => {

        if (isLoading) {
          // retry
          setTimeout(runAfterPrevActionCompletelyDispatched, 100)
        }

        // state update logic here ...

        return state
          .set('screens', fromJS(screens))
          .set('selectedScreen', fromJS(selectedScreen))
          .set('selectedScreenIds', fromJS(selectedScreenIds))
      }

      return runAfterPrevActionCompletelyDispatched()
    }
  }
}
```

Actually I hope to have a middleware or built-in functionality from redux itself to address this issue. As this is basic task for state management library that could happen in many cases. If you have other cleaner solution please post here also.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue, the solution I found rely on a change in the pattern.

According to the [redux style guide](https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide/):

1. It is strongly recommended to dispatch actions that are processed by
   several reducers.
2. It is strongly recommended to put the logic in the reducers.

Following those rules, you should avoid chaining dispatch by dispatching an action with all the data needed in the payload and then processed it in the reducer. This way, you can stop being dependent of a previous update.

Hope I am clear, hope it help